# Perl - How to create variables when looping through @_ variables

Tags: perl

I'm passing the following hash to a subroutine

```
$VAR1 = {
          'password' => 'abc123',
          'IP' => '172.18.18.122',
          'port' => '8080',
          'username' => 'sensor1'
        };
```

and I'm getting these results when I do user Dumper with `@_` variable

```
print Dumper(@_);
```

How can I loop through value pairs and create variables $IP,$username ..etc

I have created

```
my $variables;
foreach my $key ( keys @_) {
        my $key = @_->{$key}\n";
   }
```

but I always get an error.

```
Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not array dereference) at     /perl/modules/Sentinel/Api.pm line 17, near "@_) "
Compilation failed in require at agent line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at agent line 9.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, `keys` should have the following form, where `%something` is the hash whose keys you want:

```
keys( %something )
      ^
      |
```

`@_` contains a reference to a hash, so you could use the following:

```
keys( %{ $_[0] } )
```

Instead, we could give it a name:

```
my ($hash) = @_;

for my $key ( keys( %$hash ) ) {
   my $val = $hash->{$key};
   ...
}
```

That said, it sounds like you actually want the following:

```
my ($hash) = @_;

my $IP       = $hash->{IP};
my $username = $hash->{username};

...
```

If the number of references in `@_` is variable the last two snippets become

```
for my $hash ( @_ ) {
   for my $key ( keys( %$hash ) ) {
      my $val = $hash->{$key};
      ...
   }
}
```

and

```
for my $hash ( @_ ) {
   my $IP       = $hash->{IP};
   my $username = $hash->{username};
   ...
}
```

Comment: I totally missed that you asked to create variables like $IP and $username. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really a hash and that's all you're sending in, you can simply do:

```
my %hash = @_;
```

...because a hash is simply a list of key, value pairs.

If you're sending in a single hash reference:

```
my $href = shift;
```